# How do I extract the last N bytes from a System::IO::MemoryStream?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, subset, memorystream, extract

I have an `System::IO::MemoryStream` which is added to from an FTP client. How do I retrieve the last N bytes of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.seek.aspx#Y0) method with `SeekOrigin::End` to specify an offset from the end of the stream, then read your data.

```
int n = ...;
Stream^ s = ...;

s->Seek(-n, SeekOrigin::End); // minus n because we want n bytes back from the end.
array<Byte>^ data = gcnew array<Byte>(n);
s->Read(data, 0, n);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the length of the stream, then use the [Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.seek.aspx#Y0) method and read..